# When ever i typed nonsense in my linux terminal i get error

Tags: python, linux

I installed python3.8 in my Linux mint and i used  this commands to make python3.8 default

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2 
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
sudo rm usr/bin/python3
```

And when ever i typed nonsense in terminal i get this error. How can i fix the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "`/usr/lib/command-not-found`", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
```

Comment: Is that full Traceback?

Comment: What do you mean by "i typed nonsense in terminal"? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Whay did you do the final `rm`? It seems plausible that that broke something.

Comment: It seems a backslash is missing in `sudo rm usr/bin/python3`. Also why remove?

Comment: You broke your system Python. Try to reverse what you did!

Comment: That traceback looks incomplete; is there another line with the name of the exception, please?

Comment: When i typed nonsense like apk or grup or any character/alphabet. Also when i type commands which are not installed on the system.

Comment: The last line of the Traceback: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type an unknown command, some versions of Linux (including yours) try to give you suggestions for what you might have meant (or what packages you might need to install). In this case, the code for giving the suggestions is written in Python, and worked in the original version of python. In the new version, it cannot find one of its libraries, `apt_pkg`.

Possible solutions:

- Switch back to the original version of python as the default, and explicitly use python3.8 when that's what you want. If you normally use virtualenv (or similar), you only need to specify the Python version when you create a new virtual environment, not every time.

  Switching back is probably the best option.
- Install the `apt_pkg` library for the new version of Python. That will solve the immediate problem, but likely all sorts of other system scripts are also failing, and chasing down all of them will be quite tedious, frustrating and error-prone. You're likely to miss some, where the errors are non-obvious. Unless you're very thorough, you'll have a system that works poorly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be failing to find a database file, so you may need to reinstall this section of your python installation. Failing this, I suggest trying to reinstall your entire python installation and also try restarting your computer.